# How can I create a Docker image based on a git tag in the public Registry?

Tags: git, github, docker, continuous-deployment

I'm building a continuous deployment strategy using Docker. My code is hosted on Github, and the Docker registry starts an automated build when I push to git. The default setting is to start building when I push to master, and create an image with the "latest" tag. This is fine, but I want to also be able to tag commits in git and create an image based on that.
There seems to be some functionality for that on the Docker registry site, on the Edit Automated Build settings page I can select "tag" for type and provide a static tag name.

**How can I have the Docker tag name be the same as the Git tag name?**

The goal is to be able to tag specific versions so there is a version history.

Comment: Any feedback on that question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most simple solution from the command line is a nested git-rev command:

```
docker tag <image> <image>:$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)"
```

gives you e.g.

```
<image> = myImage >> myImage:67df348
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the Docker registry, under your "Automated Build" settings. By default, this makes a build called "latest" based on your "master" branch, but you can add automated builds for specific git tags as well. The picture below shows the relevant screen

[image]

Comment: Right, but instead of creating tags with hard coded names, I would like to be able to `git push --tags` any tag and have it show up as a Docker image tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue and I've sorted this out by using this plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

This is not very pretty solution but it works, so:

1) Execute shell: `echo TAG=${GIT_BRANCH#*/} > docker_tag`

2) **Inject Environment variables** Properties File Path: `docker_tag`

3) use `${TAG}` on https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Docker+Build+and+Publish+plugin